# Как растянуть Panel в Ext JS на 100% по ширине?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Почему-то получается только указать конкретное значение в пикселах.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо использовать layer: 'fit' в контейнере, содержащем рассматриваемый panel, который надо растянуть. Тогда panel займет все внутреннее пространство внутри контейнера.

Чтобы использовать контейнер, заполняющий всю страницу, можно использовать Viewport.